# how to convert a column consisting of integer data into a binary values of 1 and 0 in r studio

Tags: r

For example :

```
naffairs
0
0
3
0
3
0
0
0
7
0
0
0
0
0
```

the numbers which are other than 0 should be converted into 1 can you guys help me with a code in r studio?

Comment: See [ask]. It is unclear what your question is. Don't put questions in titles, or at least repeat it in the text of the question. [Edit] the question and tell us what you are trying to do, what you have tried along with a [mcve], and what results you get.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert it to a logical vector and then coerce to binary with `as.integer`

```
df$naffairs <- as.integer(df$naffairs != 0)
```

---

Or other option is to do the assignment to 1 based on the logical vector

```
i1 <- df$naffairs != 0
df$naffairs[i1] <- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say our values are stored into a vector named `d` then following may help you on same.

```
d[d > 0] <- 1
```

Following is execution of same or R-studio's console.

```
d <- c(0,0,3,0,3,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0)
d
 [1] 0 0 3 0 3 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0
d[d > 0] <- 1
d
 [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```